# Refreshing Sandbox and Reconnecting Marketing Cloud environment (We have all live BU's in Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, sandbox, sandbox-refresh

Are there any watch outs for when refreshing a Salesforce Sandbox Environment that is linked to a 'test' (Production type BU) in the Marketing Cloud. These environments represent our Sandbox set up.

I have refreshed the Salesforce Sandbox environment and I am now no longer able to connect the clouds from within Marketing Cloud in the **Salesforce Integrations** tab. I get the following error message: An exception occurred while saving the integration.

Comment: Currently trying to refresh the tokens and getting an error message from this help article https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214335&type=1 but getting the following error message: Line: 37, Column: 1
et4ae5.MCBaseException: An error occurred while attempting to delete user tokens. Please verify your input parameters and try again.

Comment: @user48743-->I am also getting same error like "An exception occurred while saving the integration."  how to resolve this can you please help me any body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a Sandbox Refresh, you must disconnect the integration prior to the refresh.

The connector bases its connection on the ORG ID.  A sandbox refresh changes the ORGID and therefore the system is incorrectly attached to the previous integration.

You will need to make a case with support to have the back end team correct the integration.

Steps BEFORE a sandbox refresh.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249278&type=1

Check your recycling bin for the Tokens.

Also, you must clear the API USER by using a different method.

Look under the January 2nd release to find the details on the API USER.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_latest_releases.htm&type=5